# JWT token(Azure B2C) authentication in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

An app pass a JWT bearer token(generated through Azure B2C) in Authorization Header to NodeJS REST API. So in NodeJS, how to verify the token is valid like token expiry or issuer, audience is valid.

Comment: Do you want to get a sample to show how to use nodejs to varify jwt token?

Comment: check https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi

Comment: @Tiny-wa, if any sample code which validates B2C token like issuer, aud using NodeJS

Comment: There's a ton of samples at https://jwt.io/.

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi) provided by @krishg is correct.
You mentioned in the question: What is the best way to verify that the token is valid? In fact, the most effective way to verify a token is to use the JWT library, and you cannot verify an access token by verifying a single claim.

At the same time, I do not recommend that you use your own verification logic, it is not easy to implement it correctly. MSAL/ADAL provides many methods to verify JWT, I think it is what you need. See: [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi/blob/master/index.js).

Comment: The link you provided, it has strategy like passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer',... it has oauth-bearer but how i will pass a bearer token like: Bearer eyJ0eXAiO....

Comment: @ManasKumar  You can also refer to the samples provided by jwt.io:  https://jwt.io/